# App manifest references the image which does not have a candidate in the main package error in windows phone 8.1

Tags: manifest, windows-phone-8.1

I am just creating app package and got the following error
[image]

Need help how to resolve this.

Comment: The default size is Scale 200. If you didn't include that image, Visual Studio notifies you of this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I resolved it by removing .scale-100 for your Logos name.This works for me.

Comment: I have the same issue, but don't understand the solution.  Did you change the filename?

Comment: @erotavlas: Yes. Change the filename from e.g. "image.scale-100.png" to  "image.png". This worked for me.

Comment: Simple that.. Worked for me by changing the name in file also

Answer (score 40):

In my case it had to do with the default app scale, as outlined in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maartenb/archive/2015/10/06/missing-default-200-logos-and-appx3210.aspx):

> It appears that the default scale has changed [from 100%] to 200%. OK. Fine.
>   And? Why does that matter?
>
> It matters because the main app package contains resources for
>   whatever the default scale is. And for UWP, the default is 200. Since
>   I use app bundles, my Logo-100.png ended up in a satellite app
>   package, and the main package does not have any logo (since I didn't
>   provide the default 200). Hence, my app would not be installable on a
>   system that requires scale-200.
>
> When I renamed the file to Logo.png, the editor complained because it
>   assumed that images without qualifiers were in the default scale
>   (200), and my logo didn't have the correct dimensions for that scale.
>
> There is an explanation for this in the , but it is a
>   little buried:
>
> "The default asset scale for Universal Windows apps is 200. If your
>   project includes assets not scaled at 200, you will need to add a
>   `<UapDefaultAssetScale>` element with the value of the scale of your
>   assets to this PropertyGroup. Learn more about [assets and scales](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj679352.aspx)."

So what you need to do is either change your images to the correct scale and rename their suffix accordingly (e.g. `scale-200`), or change the default scale by opening the `.csproj` file in a text editor and following the instructions in the [porting article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx) linked in said blog post:

> Find the `<PropertyGroup>` element that contains the
>   `<TargetPlatformVersion>` element. Do the
>   following steps for this `<PropertyGroup>` element
>
> The default asset scale for Universal Windows apps is 200. If your
>   project includes assets not scaled at 200, you will need to add a
>    element with the value of the scale of your
>   assets to this PropertyGroup. Learn more about assets and scales. Now
>   your  element should look similar to this example:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     …
>      <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
>     …
>      <UapDefaultAssetScale>100</UapDefaultAssetScale>
>     …
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Do not remove the scale-100 from your file names. Either create the recommended scales (scale-200, scale-400, etc) or change the default asset scale as @OhadSchneider mentions.

Comment: To reiterate this is the correct answer. For me I just opened the appmanifest file and added all the images for the scale 200 image using the UI. Visual Studio sorted out the naming conventions from there

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by making sure I had separate image files for all scale sizes. (ie. .scale-100, .scale-140, .scale-240)

Comment: This worked for me. I was building a UWP app and didn't declare all StoreLogo sizes.

Answer (score 5):

The default size is `Scale 200`. If you didn't include that image, Visual Studio notifies you of this. So include an image asset for `Scale 200`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by ending the laziness. Delete all the images that you had setup, START COMPLETELY OVER, re-assign ALL images - all 3 images for each row- set them all. That's the only way you'll know for sure that you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the name of the logo in the `AppManifest`.

For example, if you had the error on the Store Logo in the `Appmanifest ==> Store Logo ==> Store Logo : Assets/Store-Logo`

Change it to `Assets/Store-Logoooo`

then also change `Store Images` in the main app.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone.

1. From unity remove all windows icons (PLayer settings/Windows/Icons). [important]
   Will problem
2. In Unity. Add Splash screens for windows [important]
3. In Visual Studio - generate manifest all images from standard tool. [important]
   If you already have "Assets" folder - remove; And generate.

It only works like this.

Answer (score 0):

In some case the solution of renaming the images in the assets folder doesn't work out.

In that case, you should set the "**Generate App Bundle**" option at "**Never**" and continue normally with the rest of the packaging procedure.

Though this is not a permanent solution, it is a good work-around and is pretty useful if you don't necessarily want App bundles for reducing size.

Sources : Personal experience of solving this error and searching the solution on-line and finding that it worked for other users as well : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3857fb9d-dbd5-4eb8-aa75-fe4c47f26875/wp81-universal-error-image-does-not-have-a-candidate-in-main-app-package-while-creating-a-package?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 (for a desktop app): added **all** images the required sizes, and still got this message. Solved it by **first generating all images** from a base image, using the "Generate" button. Then replaced the (awful and mis-scaled) results with my own versions. Then it worked. Apparently the form that allows you to add the images is not complete, or has a mismatch with what is actually required. First using the generate option circumvents trouble.